# DocuSign embedded signing ceremony user experience video

Tags: extjs, docusignapi

I am creating embedded signature REST API POC web project using DocuSign. We are using DocuSign developer account. We have implemented the eSignature API in our project.

We are looking user experience video of DocuSign embedded signature. That we can present the video to user for understanding. Video should be for multiple signer.

Please help me out
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> We are looking user experience video of DocuSign embedded signature. That we can present the video to user for understanding. Video should be for multiple signer.

You can have a look at DocuSign's YouTube [channel](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=docusign%20embedded%20signing). The best would be to record a video yourself and emphasize the important points your integration wants to provide.

Comment: I am looking only user experience video of DocuSign embedded signature. How the signature will work. We don't want to show the any code or any url in video. We want to show just signing flow.